# Google Cloud Storage NodeJS multiple read requests loading too slow

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-storage, buffer

how do you do?

I'm trying to figure out why some requests to my Images API (usually the last ones) are taking over than 1 minute to load. The first ones are basically instantaneous. Search all over the internet, but had no apropriate answer yet. I am using Google Cloud to storage the images and NodeJS at the server, who is providing the images as a bufferized writing head to the browser.

You can check what am I saying accessing the website (18 year old content):
https://divinasacompanhantes.com/

As you can see, some images just don't load properly. I'm worried because this website is expected to have thousands more profiles, all over the world.

I am using PM2 to handle the services at the server side (2GB available memory). Here's the table:

```
┌─────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name                │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 7   │ ServiceAfiliado     │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 31312    │ 20m    │ 3    │ online    │ 0%       │ 55.9mb   │ root     │ disabled │
│ 0   │ ServiceAvaliacao    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 31249    │ 20m    │ 3    │ online    │ 0%       │ 55.2mb   │ root     │ disabled │
│ 8   │ ServiceBlog         │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 31330    │ 20m    │ 3    │ online    │ 0%       │ 61.1mb   │ root     │ disabled │
│ 1   │ ServiceChat         │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 31256    │ 20m    │ 3    │ online    │ 0%       │ 57.3mb   │ root     │ disabled │
│ 9   │ ServiceConfig       │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 31337    │ 20m    │ 3    │ online    │ 0%       │ 56.2mb   │ root     │ disabled │
│ 10  │ ServiceImage        │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 31904    │ 0s     │ 13   │ online    │ 0%       │ 19.1mb   │ root     │ disabled │
│ 2   │ ServiceLead         │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 31269    │ 20m    │ 3    │ online    │ 0%       │ 54.8mb   │ root     │ disabled │
│ 3   │ ServiceMail         │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 31276    │ 20m    │ 3    │ online    │ 0%       │ 43.3mb   │ root     │ disabled │
│ 4   │ ServicePagamento    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 31289    │ 20m    │ 3    │ online    │ 0%       │ 42.5mb   │ root     │ disabled │
│ 5   │ ServiceParceiro     │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 31296    │ 20m    │ 3    │ online    │ 0%       │ 60.1mb   │ root     │ disabled │
│ 6   │ ServicePerfil       │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 31309    │ 20m    │ 3    │ online    │ 0%       │ 69.7mb   │ root     │ disabled │
└─────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

The route handling this specific request:

```
router.get('/image/:imageId', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        let imageId = req.param('imageId')
        let returnImage = await cloudController.getImageFromBucket('fotos_perfil', imageId)

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'});
        returnImage.on('data', (data) => {
            res.write(data)
        })
        returnImage.on('error', (error) => {
            res.status(400).send('Erro lendo a imagem')
            console.error(error)
        })
        returnImage.on('end', () => {
            res.end()
        })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error')
    }
})
```

And the controller associated:

```
async function getImageFromBucket(bucket, imageId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let imageInfo = storage.bucket(bucket).file(imageId).createReadStream()
            resolve(imageInfo)
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e)
        }
    })
}
```

Can anyone provide me some ideas to solve this? I've read the official Google documentation and the tip is to use `fast-crc32c`, but only. No clues on how to configure...